# ViewPager2 and PageTransformer selects wrong page randomly

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, android-pagetransformer

I have a viewpager2 added under a ConstraintLayout and set with a PageTransformer to show previous and next page previews

```html
private void setPageMargin(ViewPager2 viewpager2) {
        viewpager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        float nextItemVisiblePx = mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.viewpager_next_item_visible);
        float currentItemHorizontalMarginPx = mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin);
        viewpager2.setPageTransformer((page, position) -> {
            float offset = position * -(2 * nextItemVisiblePx + currentItemHorizontalMarginPx);
            if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(viewpager2) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
                page.setTranslationX(-offset);
            } else {
                page.setTranslationX(offset);
            }
            if (position < -1)
                page.setAlpha(0.5f);
            else if (position <= 1) {
                page.setAlpha(Math.max(0.5f, 1 - Math.abs(position)));
            } else page.setAlpha(0.5f);
        });


    }
```

When I set viewpager2.setcurrentItem(pos), it selects wrong page in a random manner.
Please anyone can point out what could be the possible issue here?

Comment: Hardcoding this value might be the cause `.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)`, unless it's `4` pages. Without the actual code of the `PagerAdapter`, the description of the issue is almost is as good as "it's not working"... that `PageTransformer` code is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @MartinZeitler 3 is set to show 3 pages(2 previews on either side and the current page).Pager adapter is simply setting on the item layout using databinding